# which Ubuntu should I install for a low spec computer

Tags: system-installation, hardware, performance

I want to install Ubuntu but my computer specs are very low and I don't know which Ubuntu I should download. I want to install Ubuntu but my PC is a Compaq Mini 110.

It has:

- 70 GB of free of disk space
- 1 GB RAM
- 32 bit system
- Intel Atom CPU N270 / 1 GHz

I currently have Windows 7. So I want to have both windows and Ubuntu on my PC.

Comment: Ubuntu with unity will not work OK on this hardware. I sugget Lubuntu 14.04.4 32-bit. It should work at leaset acceptable.

Comment: Try Lubuntu http://lubuntu.me It is the absolute "lightest" of the Ubuntu flavors. **Be very careful on the partition screen** of the installation to make sure you are installing alongside Windows, not replacing Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to askubuntu!

Ubuntu can run nicely on older PCs. If you need something even lighter, you can try out [different flavours](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors), including very lightweight ones, such as [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me/).

It's not very hard to set up dual-boot, i recommend you to follow the steps on [this arcticle](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).
If you need any help, feel free to ask!

---

Regarding the release, you can chose between a regular release and a LTS one, both have their pros and cons.

Regular: Released every 6 months and Supported for 9 months, they're a great choice if you want to always get the latest features and packages.
The current latest release is (At the time of writting)  15.10 (Wily Werewolf).

LTS: Released every 2 years, they are Supported during 5 years. They're the best choice if what you're looking for is stability.
The current latest LTS release is (At the time of writting) 14.04.3 (Trusty Tahr).

If you want to read more about the different releases, here's a few links:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

---

PS: If my post answered your question, please remember to mark it as [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the 32-bit version of ubuntu, it will run well on you hardware and the base OS will not take up a large amount of space.

Please ask for help if you have trouble with dual boot install or disk partitioning.

You will want to install Ubuntu 14.04LTS until June or July when 16.04LTS is stable enough to work consistently.

I have 16.04LTS installed on a macbook and I have had to do a bit of debugging and if you are new to Ubuntu then you will want to start with a well documented and supported version.

Comment: yes but what version i should download 15.10 desktop or 14.04.4 desktop which of this is better for a low pc

Comment: you will want 15.10 desktop 32-bit version

Comment: @Rocket Why 15.10?

Comment: @Pilot6, Just edited [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/750723/435188) to help you chose your version, please take a look at it.

Comment: It is the newest version and will have the most compatibility with your system, the 32-bit version will be the most complete.